# How to use a dependency property defined in custom class?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, dependency-properties

I have a class that define some custom dependency properties for `TextBox` class:

```
public class DependencyProperties:FrameworkElement 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionBeginProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionBegin", typeof(int), typeof(TextBox),
                                                          new UIPropertyMetadata(0, SelectionStartDependencyPropertyChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionLengthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionLength", typeof(int), typeof(TextBox),
                                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(0, SelectionLengthDependencyPropertyChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Children", typeof (string), typeof (TreeView));

    static DependencyProperties() 
    {

    }
 ...     
}
```

And when I try to use these properties in Xaml:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox_1735"
         SelectionBegin="{Binding TextBox_1735SelectionBegin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         SelectionLength="{Binding TextBox_1735SelectionLength, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

It raise an exception that the property `SelectionBegin` can't be resolved.

Comment: In your case you need to implement the *attached* dependency property - [`MSDN link`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx). And use like this: `<TextBox local:DependencyProperties.SelectionBegin={...} />`.

Comment: I tried. But now I get another error: "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SetSelectionBegin' property of type 'TextBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

Comment: @Sergiu You made a mistake somewhere when you implemented your [custom attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx#custom)..

Answer (score 0):

What you should be looking for is [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the standard dependency properties have to be declared in the control itself. You also could inherit from TextBox and add your dependency properties in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple class that should look something like with some remarks. By this example you can make yourself the remaining properties.

**`AttachedProperty`**

```
public class DependencyProperties
{
    #region Here put your property declaration

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionBeginProperty;

    public static void SetSelectionBegin(DependencyObject DepObject, int value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(SelectionBeginProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetSelectionBegin(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (int)DepObject.GetValue(SelectionBeginProperty);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Here in constructor register you property

    static DependencyProperties()
    {
        SelectionBeginProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectionBegin", // RegisterAttached
                                                             typeof(int),              // Type of your property
                                                             typeof(DependencyProperties), // Name of your class
                                                             new UIPropertyMetadata(0, SelectionStartDependencyPropertyChanged));
    }

    #endregion

    private static void SelectionStartDependencyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        // Some logic
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;

        if (textBox == null) 
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.NewValue is int && ((int)e.NewValue) > 0)
        {
            textBox.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

**`XAML`**

```
<Window x:Class="AttachedPropertyHelp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AttachedPropertyHelp"
        Name="MyWindow" Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" 
                 local:DependencyProperties.SelectionBegin="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=MyWindow}" 
                 Width="100"
                 Height="30" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For *attached* dependency property sets the Width of the `Window` Int type and if it is greater than zero, then the `TextBox` marked red Background.